# Linux - Copy the files (not subfolders) from origin to destination while overwriting/deleting the initial contents in the destination folder

Tags: linux

I need to run a command in Linux where I would copy the files (not folders) in `~/folder1/subfolder1` to `~/folder2/subfolder2` while deleting the initial contents/files in `folder2`?
Command cp copies files from one folder to another:

```
cp ~/folder1/* ~/folder2/
```

But, how can I also delete files that were initially in the folder2, while copying only files from folder1?
Also, is there a `rsync` command instead of `cp` that would only copy files and not subfolders?
I have tried with this:

```
rsync --delete-during folder1/* folder2/
```

But, I got an error:

```
rsync: --delete does not work without -r or -d.
```

And I don't want to use -r or -d flag since that would mean the subfolders would get copied as well, and I only want to copy files.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve ... 

Delete all files under folder2, or only the files that are in folder1?

By saying "I would copy files (not folders)" and "I don't want to use -r or -d flag since that would mean the subfolders would get copied as well" I understand that if dir x under 1 does not exist under 2 you don't want it copied, otherwise it doesn't matter if you copy the folders or not (and thus rsync -a with some delete option would do)

Comment: As it is stated in the question, I would like to delete all of the content in the destination folder, so in this case folder2. I am not sure why do you think rsync -a with some delete option would do, because if you run that, it copies the subfolder from folder1 to folder2, which I said I don't want to do.

Comment: But you do want the same subfolder structure under folder2 as in folder1?

To delete file contents of a directory but preserving the subdirectories, you can use find:

find folder2 -type f -exec rm {} \;

Comment: No, I don't want any subfolders from folder1, just files, nothing else. Just to copy files from folder1 to folder2, while deleting content from folder2.

Comment: If the same file already exists in subfolder2, cp -f will overwrite the file. If you want to delete the contents of subfolder2 first, run rm -f ~/folder2/subfolder2/* && find ~/folder1/subfolder1 -type f -exec cp '{}' ~/folder2/subfolder2 \;

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete everything in folder2, then copy every file from folder1 ?

Try something like this:

```
rm folder2/* && cp folder1/* folder2/
```

(cp will not copy directories by default)